how to set specific object animation with three.js
I'm new for three.js how I can config specific object animation? I tried but it doesn't work, i need to create loop move up and down object_22
please someone guide me, appreciate :)
const Island = ({ isMobile, isRotating }) => {
    const { scene, animations } = useGLTF("./alien_planet/scene.gltf");
    const { actions } = useAnimations(animations);
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isRotating) {
          actions["Object_22"].play();
        } else {
          actions["Object_22"].stop();
        }
      }, [actions, isRotating]);
  

  return (
    <mesh ref={ref}>
      <hemisphereLight  intensity={0.1} groundColor='black' />
      <pointLight intensity={20} />
      <primitive
        object={scene}
        scale={isMobile ? 0.8 : 1.2}
        position={isMobile ? [0, -3, -2.2] : [0, -3.3, 0.5]}
        rotation={[-0.01, 1, -0.05]}
      />
    </mesh>
    
  );
};

now my error is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stop')
